# Pi cron php not running

Tags: linux, cron, php

I can't get this cron to run.

being new to linux, I really don't know my way around.

Pi 3B+
Debian 9 Stretch
PHP 7.0.33
Nginx 1.10.3

Pi has OpenMediaVault ( OMV ) running.
Used OMV to create a sharedfolder 'www' which I can access and also map to my PC as a network folder.
I have php scripts in the www folder and they execute correctly when accessed from the pC browser.

I want to automate 1 of the php scripts, which I assume is done using crontab.

Used Putty to login to the Pi as user root
edit crontab with :

```
crontab -e
```

scrolled down and added :

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php
```

I understand this will run every 1 minute - using that only as a test.
I have tested the push2.php code from my browser and it executes as expected without errors.

When cron runs, I get an error report email to my PC ( I assume generated by OMV ) to say :

```
Could not open input file: /mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Verify that the file is actually located at the path that you enter into the crontab. Does `ls -ld /mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php` actually output anything?

Comment: no.
root@OMVpi1:~# ls -ld /mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php
ls: cannot access '/mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php': No such file or directory

Comment: So, the file is located elsewhere.

Comment: how would I find the path to the file ?

root@OMVpi1:/# ls -ld /mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php
ls: cannot access '/mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php': No such file or directory
root@OMVpi1:/# cd /mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/
-bash: cd: /mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/: No such file or directory
root@OMVpi1:/# cd /mnt
root@OMVpi1:/mnt# cd/fs
-bash: cd/fs: No such file or directory
root@OMVpi1:/mnt# ls -a
.  ..
root@OMVpi1:/mnt# pwd
/mnt

Comment: sorry. new to this platform. how do I paste 'code' so it remains formatted ?

Comment: root@OMVpi1:/mnt# cd /
root@OMVpi1:/# locate push1
/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push1.php
/srv/dev-disk-by-label-NAShd1/www/testcode/push1.php

Comment: this got some result : root@OMVpi1:/# ls -ld /sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 root users 512 Sep 26 09:54 /sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php
root@OMVpi1:/#

Comment: Why did you think the file's path was what you first wrote?

Comment: ok. changed the cron to this, and it worked. I just don't understand why, because it only has half the path : `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php `

Comment: @Kusalananda - because when I look at the location in Cloud Commander, then that is the path to the www folder.

Comment: Is it possible that `/mnt/fs` is your root folder (at `/`) when you log in using `ssh`, i.e. that your whole `ssh` session is `chroot`-ed to the `/mnt/fs` directory?

Comment: @Kusalananda, firstly, a BIG Thank You for your help. I have been struggling for hours on this. How would I tell if '/mnt/fs' is the root folder when I log in to Putty using user 'root' ?

Comment: if I go `cd /` and then `ls -a` it appears to show the folders that I see in Cloud Commander in `/mnt/fs/`

Comment: Ok, so you're put into a chrooted environment when you log in with `ssh`, good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the file is `/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php`, not `/mnt/fs/sharedfolders/www/testcode/push2.php`.

From comments, it appears as if you're put into a chrooted environment under `/mnt/fs` when you log in using `ssh`.  This is why the pathname of the file starts with `/sharedfolders` rather than with `/mnt/fs`.  The `/mnt/fs` directory is the root directory of your `ssh` session.

Comment: Thank You @Kusalananda. I really appreciate your expert advice and solution and explanation.